Uniquenss of pivotal structure on a unitary fusion category
I'm reading a lecture note about topological order An invitation to topological orders and category theory, where in page 50 the author gives the statement that
A unitary fusion category admits a unique pivotal structure defined by (with a
normalized choice of duals)
$$
a_x=(b_x^\dagger\otimes 1_{x^{LL}})\circ(1_{x}\otimes b_{x^L})
=(1_{x^{LL}}\otimes d_x)\circ (d^\dagger_{x^L}\otimes 1_x)
$$
where $a:x\to x^{LL}$ is a pivotal structure, $b_x:1\to x\otimes x^L$ is coevaluation morphism and $d_x:x^L\otimes x\to 1$ is the evaluation morphism. And the meaning of "with a normalized choice of duals" is that $d_y\circ d_y^\dagger=b_y^\dagger \circ b_y$ for any object $y$.
My question is, how can one prove this statement? (i.e. the uniqueness and why this expression) I will appreciate it if someone can show me a proof or a reference for that.
